# How do I make sure that a new window has opened in my protractor test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to figure out how to check that a new window has opened and that the URL is correct

Every time I try to check that a new window has opened, the test just time outs because I can't figure out how to switch tabs

Is there a way to click a button that opens a new tab and to check that the url is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Selenium, you will need to switch to the proper window handle when opening a new tab before you can perform any functions on it. You'll need to execute some additional code to get the window handles, and switch to the newly opened one as such:

```
// save parent window handle in case you need to switch back to it
var parentWindow=handles[0];

// switch to 2nd opened window, perform a function on it
driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
    driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function(){
        // verify the correct URL here
    });
});

// switch back to parent
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: do you know how to check if the new 'window' is actually an opening of mail client - like clicking on a `mailto:` link ?